# 14.04 - Can't print since 3.16-0-51-generic kernel update - how to report bug

Tags: kernel, bug-reporting

I've confirmed that the problem is due to today's kernel update by rolling back to the -50 kernel and regaining the ability to print. I want to file a bug but I don't know where to start regarding a kernel bug.  Please advise.

Edit: In case anyone has this same problem and comes looking, bug is [1507863](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1507863)

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs

Comment: Will do - gimme a minute to make it look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred method of reporting kernel bugs is done by using the terminal. To open the terminal press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. When the terminal is open you enter `ubuntu-bug linux` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button.

When you're submitting a bug it is important to give as much information as possible. They'd like you to include a few things so be prepared for and include at least the following information:

1. The majority of kernel bug are hardware specific so be sure to note what hardware/device is being used.

   Document any known steps to reproduce the bug.

   Also note whether the bug exists in previous kernel versions of Ubuntu or if it's a regression from previous kernel versions.

   Finally, it's critical to also make sure to test the latest development Ubuntu kernel version as well as the latest upstream mainline kernel.

This should cover most use cases. If you find this impossible or need additional information then please see the [official Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs) page about filing bug reports.